# Open File - Security Warning dialog box

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

How do i disable this Open File - Security Warning dialog box? everything i find involves adding ip's to trusted sites etc. but this application is installed locally. I've already unblocked the exe from the properties window, however that didn't help

Comment: What operating system? Windows XP? Vista? Windows 7?

Comment: And which IE version? (IE8 deploys different security settings even for normal explorer...) And is the file on a network share or on a local disk?

Comment: It's windows xp on IE7

Comment: Is the executable accessing other files?  You have to unblock all files associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try right clicking the exe file and select properties.

If there is an unblock button on the General tab click that and it shouldn't bother you again

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IE 7/8, Go to Tools / Internet Options / Security and click on the local Intranet Icon. Then, click the sites button. Make sure "Automatically detect Intranet Network" is unchecked and the following items are checked, "Include all lical (intranet) sites not listed in other zones", Include all sites that bypass the proxy server", and "Include all network paths (UNC's)".

I would only do this is the file you are try to access / execute is located on your local file server and unblocking the file is not working. I used to have this problem with our ERP application who's .exe file resided on our file server. After upgrading our clients web browsers from IE6 to IE 7 or 8 we started to get the same error message. The above steps are what fixed it.

Danbo

Answer (score 1):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Download]
"CheckExeSignatures"="no"
"RunInvalidSignatures"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments]
"SaveZoneInformation"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations]
"LowRiskFileTypes"=".zip;.rar;.nfo;.txt;.exe;.bat;.com;.cmd;.reg;.msi;.htm;.html;.gif;.bmp;.jpg;.avi;.mpg;.mpeg;.mov;.mp3;.m3u;.wav;"
```

More here :
http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/58926-turn-off-open-file-security-warning/

Comment: -1 that looks ok but not so great, the msfn link shows the poster that wrote that "MGadAllah", and there's clearly backslashes missing in "[HKEY_CURRENT_USERSoftwareMic"  Maybe if you put them in it'll work. I notice it's similar to http://superuser.com/questions/324954/how-can-i-disable-the-open-file-security-warning-when-i-want-to-run-downloaded   But your one has an extra line at the top

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click shortcut
2. Click **Properties**
3. Highlight shortcut tab
4. Click Advanced
5. Tick "Run as administrator"
6. Click **Apply**

All done and sorted. Worked for me on Windows 8.1.