# How can I disable the "Open File Security Warning" when I want to run downloaded executable files?

Tags: windows-7, security, windows-registry

I would like to disable the "Open File Security Warning" that says "Do you want to run this file?" whenever I double click on an .exe I download. I have Windows 7 Home Premium, so I don't have the group policies editor. I have tried setting a registry value: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations, value DefaultFileTypeRisk to 6152, but this did no good. This is the only entry under Associations, incidentally, and it was empty before I added this.

Is there a way to disable this message on my system (other than unblocking each .exe file)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding these two registry entries prevent the error message "Open File Security Warning" that says "Do you want to run this file?" in Windows 7. As when disabling most security warnings, you should think it through before you do it.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments]
"SaveZoneInformation"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations]
"LowRiskFileTypes"=".zip;.rar;.nfo;.txt;.exe;.bat;.com;.cmd;.reg;.msi;.htm;.html;.gif;.bmp;.jpg;.avi;.mpg;.mpeg;.mov;.mp3;.m3u;.wav;"
```

Comment: Note that adding a "." to that list should make it so files without an extension don't prompt either. (though they will only prompt if you had tweaked a default opening program first)

Comment: Is there a way to disable it for all files, no exceptions? I have been clicking on that box for decades, and I have never once clicked no. I do not want to see that popup again, ever. Not even for files I downloaded long ago. Fed up I am.

Comment: I tried doing as instructed. The two keys did not exist, so I created them. What type of value should LowRiskFileTypes have, BTW? Maybe I copied something wrong, but after I did it and rebooted, the system slowed to crawl. I did a system-restore and all was well again, except of course I still get the blasted popups. How frustrating.