# How safe/unsafe is this method of disabling the ridiculous "open file - security warning"

Tags: windows-7, security, internet-explorer, vbscript

I created a vbs file and tried to run it and got the silly warning a bit like

[image]

I see there are a few solutions to it.  One is  [mentioned here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-us/e3008c75-48b4-4a6c-bc14-5a20ce72cd7f/disable-open-file-security-warning?forum=itproxpsp)

In IE-  tools..internet options..security tab..custom level.."Launching applications and unsafe files" Enabled (as opposed to prompt).

and  start...run..gpedit.msc  administrative templates..windows components..internet explorer.."Turn off the security settings check feature) Enabled that.

I would like to know how insecure that option is. Is it totally safe? (By that I mean, is it going to cause IE to do something stupid like download a file automatically without asking me? or run something without asking me - something I didn't double click on).

i.e. is it something that me or pretty much any reasonably technical person would be well advised to do?

I don't want IE to automatically download something without a prompt(which IE maybe used to do like pre Win XP Sp2!)   If I double click an executable file or script, I don't want a warning by virtue of it being an executable or script. (I know it is and I double clicked it to run it, and i'm aware of the nature of these things). I just don't want IE doing something stupid and insecure. But I don't want IE or Windows trying to be clever and being a nuisance.

I notice there are other ways too like this involving the registry [here](https://superuser.com/questions/324954/how-can-i-disable-the-open-file-security-warning-when-i-want-to-run-downloaded) and i'd be interested to know how they compare from a security standpoint.  (no doubt the least intrusive is [using sysinternals streams on the file or folder of files](http://www.akaplan.com/blog/2009/04/remove-open-file-security-warning-for-files-downloaded-from-the-internet/) but i'm interested in the security of the method I mentioned compared to the one involving the registry.

Comment: no, disabling this check is utter folly. much better to unblock the file in its properties -> Advanced -> unblock. also I'd advise you to run your script at the command line with 'cscript path'. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490887.aspx

Comment: @FrankThomas  care to state what bad thing it'd cause to disable the "check"?  btw there's nothing wrong with wscript, i'm using for a case where I don't want to run something from the cmd prompt. so, no cmd window pops up.

Comment: it would allow any server you contact online to load and execute a script file within your browser session. keep in mind, the issue is not your particular script, but your environments configuration. thats why I suggest you unblock the specific script, rather than allowing all scripts to execute regardless of their origin.

Comment: @FrankThomas  Even before the change, just given the default windows and IE settings, I have never been stopped from running something like this  http://www.christersvensson.com/calculator/ (an online javascript calculator), it runs by default,  so what do you mean-  can you give an example?

Comment: javascript uses a differant mechnaism called the same-origin policy to determine when scripts execute. javascript uses the browsers built in built in engine, and executes within a sandbox. activex and vbs however execute via an client-side external runtime. Instead IE determines what to do by security zone, which is what you are considering configuring. COM and MS scripting gets far more access to your local system than javascript and is a lot more dangerous. that combined with being IE only, are pretty much why legit sites don't use it anymore. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: I just tested a webpage with within the HTML head tags, <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">msgbox "test"</SCRIPT>  it ran in IE (though chrome for some reason isn't displaying the msgbox).  And it ran on a computer which just had Win7 installed and no settings changed. So so far i've tried two examples and not seen any difference. I'm not denying it, but can you give me a more concrete example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11132/discussion-between-barlop-and-frank-thomas)